# How to create a random String using the current timestamp as the salt in Java?

Tags: java, random, timestamp

I would like to create a random string (to output to the console for debugging purposes) based off of the current timestamp.

For example, the console would output:

```
Setting up browser [123456]...
Getting configuration [758493]...
Completed: [758493].
Completed: [123456].
```

Here the `123456` and `758493` are the random strings I'm trying to generate.

Here's the pseudocode for how I think it can work:

```
private String random(int len){
long ts = getCurrentTimestamp;
String value = createRandom(len, ts); 
    //len is the length of the randomString
    //and ts is the salt
return value;
}
```

Can anyone help with the details of this (what needs to be imported), and/or possibly suggest improvements to this?

Answer (score 6):

Well it depends on what you mean by "current timestamp". You could use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29), but that won't necessarily be *unique* - if you call it several times in a short period, you may well get the same results several times. There's also [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).

As an alternative, you could use [`UUID.randomUUID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29), either using all the bits or some subset. (If you decide to use a subset, you should choose them carefully. Not all bits in a UUID are equal.)

Comment: Thank you Jon for your suggestions!  Can you see my other comment under @Spaeth's answer and please tell me what you think about it?

Comment: @rishimaharaj: It seems reasonable, but I think I'd probably go with `UUID` personally.

Answer (score 2):

How about MD5 from the `System.nanoTime()`?

```
MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] messageDigest = instance.digest(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()).getBytes());
StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
    if (hex.length() == 1) {
        // could use a for loop, but we're only dealing with a single
        // byte
        hexString.append('0');
    }
    hexString.append(hex);
}
return hexString.toString();
```

Result for 4 invocations:

```
bbf9123ac9335581535350e863236800
67fef4376523ae683b2e1d54fd97df53
ef1e747dc916584baed73a0921410216
8c8bc839bf739210a3875966430879de
```

Comment: I like the System.nanoTime suggestion.  What do you think about this: `Long.toString(System.nanoTime()).substring(9);`?

Comment: System.nanoTime returns a 16 digit number.  `substring(9) ` cut off the first 9 digits (which were all the same, and gave me more random looking, but sensible digits leftover).  From `1145968877460237` and `1145968878065213` to `7460237` and `8065213`.

Answer (score -8):

Key-based on current timestamp:

```
npm install random-key-generator
```

Comment: Notice the Java tag on this question.