# How Does Java Produce a Random Number?

Tags: java, random

I know you can use Math.random() in Java to generate a random double from 0.0 to 1.0, but *how* does the computer pick a number? What code is the computer following to simulate randomness?

Comment: you better read this articles 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/java_util_random_algorithm.shtml#.Vlpu9OKRbEk should be the non-secure one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easily found by looking at the docs since, happily, the behavior is well-defined in Java. From [`Math`, it says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--)

> When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>
> `new java.util.Random()`

Sadly it doesn't explicitly say which method on `Random` it calls. However, since its return value is in the same range as `Random.nextDouble`, which it also links to in the "See Also" section, it should be a safe assumption that that is what is used.

Looking at [`Random.nextDouble`, you can see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble--)

> ```
> return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27))
>   / (double)(1L << 53);
> ```

And [`next` is implemented as](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next-int-)

> atomically updating the seed to
>
> `(seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)`
>
> and returning
>
> `(int)(seed >>> (48 - bits))`

So the final random value is calculated as

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
next1 = (int)(seed >>> (48 - 26))
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
next2 = (int)(seed >>> (48 - 27))
randomValue = (((long)next1 << 27) + next2) / (double)(1L << 53);
```

Where

> the seed of the random number generator [is initialized as] a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.

[as stated in the `Random` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random--)

By looking at this, it should be pretty clear that the number is not, in fact, "random" as most people would understand it. It's a completely predictable mathematical pattern, known as [pseudorandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which is random enough for many purposes. However, it might be worth looking into [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) (which produces unpredictable, cryptographically strong random values), depending on how unpredictable you want the results to be.

Answer (score 1):

The truth about random numbers is that they are not really random. they are just calculation with the current time in mili/nano(or even less)-seconds... because time is always change and never being repeat the value can't be the same value for the "same reason" that whats make random number a random number...

Check out @FranciscoSpaeth answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11317929/3180983

Comment: That is a pretty bad approach (for general purpose random) and hopefully found nowhere in production. Time is a bad random seed since it can be manipulated and it may be unchanged between calls because processors can run faster than the clock ticks. 1 GHz = 0.0000010 ms cycles. Also on multiple cores in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You can trace it down in Java class declarations. This one's from Math.class:

```
public static double random() {
    return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}
```

It's easily done in Eclipse. Focus & F3.

Comment: I'd down vote you because @tethernova ask how random number is being generated...

Comment: You can do it if you want. I gave my tip for trying and sorting this out on one's own.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code of the Random class in java you see that it depends if you are using a seed or not - i.e calling public Random() or calling public Random(long seed).

From the source code of the Java Random class:

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}

private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 1181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}

private static final AtomicLong seedUniquifier
    = new AtomicLong(8682522807148012L);
```

You see that if you do not specify a seed the class Random uses a AtomicLong seed and performs a bitwise XOR operation (^) using System.nanoTime()

However if you DO specify a seed another part of the code is called with no invocation of System.nanoTime().

(Note that if you call without a seed the constructor using a seed is called nontheless but with a seed consisting of System.nanoTime() which guarantees a different seed with each invocation)

```
public Random(long seed) {
    if (getClass() == Random.class)
        this.seed = new AtomicLong(initialScramble(seed));
    else {
        // subclass might have overriden setSeed
        this.seed = new AtomicLong();
        setSeed(seed);
    }
}

private static long initialScramble(long seed) {
    return (seed ^ multiplier) & mask;
}
```

The seed will first be scrambled by calling the method initialScramble(long seed)

With the call from the code by nextBytes, nextLong, nextInt etc.. next() is called. Its implementation is as follows:

```
 protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
    oldseed = seed.get();
    nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

It basically contains the "Linear congruential generator" in the line

```
nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
```

You can test the difference between a call with and without a seed. If you provide a seed and call the methods nextInt, nextBytes etc only once you will get the same value each time.
However if you do not specify a seed you will get a different value even if you call the methods nextInt, nextBytes etc only once.